# CompanionDeviceManager without using an intent chooser and scanning

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-8.0-oreo

I already have mac addresses of the Bluetooth device that I need to connect to. I do not wish to ask for any location permission. when my app is launched I need to scan and connect to the Bluetooth device using the mac address that is specified. Companion Device pairing that has been introduced in the latest android version.. I do not wish to open a chooser and get the callback result in onActivityResult. If there is any other way I could route all the scanning done by the Companion Device.

```
deviceManager.associate(pairingRequest,
    object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
        // Called when a device is found. Launch the IntentSender so the user
        // can select the device they want to pair with.
        override fun onDeviceFound(chooserLauncher: IntentSender) {
            startIntentSenderForResult(chooserLauncher,
                SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0)
        }

        override fun onFailure(error: CharSequence?) {
            // Handle the failure.
        }
    }, null)
```

in the below code if there is any way I could use a different mechanism so that my scanning can happen and I get the result somewhere and it does not ask for a dialog box for the user to enter.

```
 startIntentSenderForResult(chooserLauncher,
                    SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0)
```

or is there any way to use bluetooth functionality without asking for location permission?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No. I did not @dogwasstar

Comment: I am trying to do the same.  But we really can't extract data from IntentSender.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: nope @ShellyPritchard

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the mac address there is no need to scan. You can use

```
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(macAddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(staticBtMac).build()
val ledeviceFilter: BluetoothLeDeviceFilter = BluetoothLeDeviceFilter.Builder()
    .setScanFilter(scanFilter)
    .build()
```

Before you create the **pairingRequest** above in AssociationRequest.Builder

You would

```
val pairingRequest: AssociationRequest = AssociationRequest.Builder()
    .addDeviceFilter(ledeviceFilter)
    .setSingleDevice(true)
```

This will not list devices but just a permission pop up dialog with ->

"Allow 'Appname' to access your 'BT ADV Device name'" [Allow] [Don't Allow] buttons. It looks slightly different depending on if its Pixel or Samsung or other phone but it comes down to simple yes/no.

There is also the
`..setSelfManaged(true)`
But this involves far more complexity and even more interaction with the framework.

If you really want to get into it you can see the actual code at https://cs.android.com/